# "be reserved for" definition

Tags: meaning

what does "reserved for" imply here in the following sentences ? I delved into the definitions to come up with something but none seem to be coherent or fitting.

*"What I now call the “loser mentality” is not **reserved for** extreme cases like drug addicts, felons, and so forth.  Sometimes otherwise nice, decent people are actually living a “loser” life"*

*"I could never understand ethnic or national pride, because to me pride should be **reserved for** something you achieve our attain on your own"*

Answer (score 2):

It means that is isn't **exclusively used in conjunction with**...

The expression "loser mentality" is quite derogatory, so the author is trying to persuade the reader that its application need not be limited to extreme cases, but that there are "lesser *crimes*" that also deserve the title.

This is a common use of the expression "not [only|just] reserved for" as "reserved" here implies an exclusivity, in the same way a table in a restaurant is reserved for a single dining party.

Contrast this with the latter sentence.  The meaning is the same, but this time instead of the author saying the term should be more broadly applied, they are saying that it is too broadly applied.

HTH.